Were the porno videos in the VideoDome real videos?
In Parks and Recreation's S5E16, "Bail-out", the Pawnee VideoDome temporarily becomes a XXX Adult DVD Emporium with porn videos lining the sets for most of the episode.
There are even some close-ups of specific ones, including "Spanks for Coming To Dinner", "High Hell Hellcats", and "Hot Tub Nurses", among a ton of others that aren't in focus long enough to identify.
Basic Googling isn't bringing up those videos aside from being in this episode, but they also seem more authentic than most Parks and Recreation sight gags.
Were these real videos? Or props purchased or made for the episode? Or a mix of the two?

A quick search indicates that these are fake titles slapped over stock photographs. Note that they've unnecessarily blurred parts of the (actually quite tame) photos to make them look more 'adult'



Interesting... did you have a source that gave you those? The reason I ask is because I can certainly see that the four featured in the slow zoom in are stock photos, but I was wondering if the big sweeping shots of the store were also known to be props. I would be genuinely surprised if they made props for every movie.

@GGMG-he-him - Each one is a stock photo with some words printed on it, colour printed in the props office and stuck into a DVD box. I'd be astounded if a single real film was anywhere on that set given the ease by which you can make these fakes

@GGMG-he-him - They don't appear to have replaced all of them from the prior set dressing. I can see a few of the old "art film" boxes in the background shots.
